# How do I configure Apache Shiro to use the principal from the HTTP session?

Tags: single-sign-on, shiro, http-authentication, principal, cxf-fediz

I have a set up where I need to combine the two security frameworks CXF Fediz and Shiro. I've set up my system in such a way that the `FederationFilter` does the login via an SSO service. That means I already have the principal in the HTTP session.

I'm using a library which depends on Shiro for authentication. As I understand Shiro, it also wants to authenticate the current user against some external authority (LDAP, AD, etc). I don't need that since Fediz has already done this for me.

How do I configure Shiro to simply use the existing HTTP principal which Fediz has created?